# use_certificate_chain_file: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, asio

I'm trying to create an acceptor using boost::asio which is wrapper around openssl. but i get errors while trying to set the certificate chain file and the private key file

OS: Windows
compiler: MSVC
I'm using vcpkg for both boost and openssl however I have another openssl 1.1.1 installed in another directory (not used in compilation). I didn't find any configuration file in any directory related to openssl. I tried many ways to solve this including reading every other posts on this topic but no chance and spent almost a month trying to solve this problem. I have also looked up the boost's wrapper implementation and still couldn't find the reason.

```
Acceptor::Acceptor(asio::io_service &ios, unsigned short port_num)
    : m_ios(ios),
      m_acceptor(m_ios,
                 asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                     asio::ip::address_v4::any(),
                     port_num)),
      m_ssl_context(asio::ssl::context::sslv23_server)
{
    // Setting up the context.
    m_ssl_context.set_options(
        boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds | 
        boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
        boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    m_ssl_context.set_password_callback(
        [this](std::size_t max_length,
               asio::ssl::context::password_purpose purpose)
            -> std::string
        { return get_password(max_length, purpose); });
    // to find default location
    const char* dir;
    m_ssl_context.set_default_verify_paths();
    dir = X509_get_default_cert_dir();
    puts(dir);
    dir = X509_get_default_private_dir();
    puts(dir);
    try {
        m_ssl_context.load_verify_file("SomePath/server.crt"); // makes no difference
        m_ssl_context.use_certificate_chain_file("server.crt");
        m_ssl_context.use_private_key_file("server.key",
            asio::ssl::context::pem);
        m_ssl_context.use_tmp_dh_file("dh512.pem");
    }
    catch (system::system_error err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
    m_acceptor.listen();
}
```

this is my output until end of this function.

OUTPUT:
**SomePath/certs
SomePath/private
use_certificate_chain_file: The system cannot find the file specified [system:2]**

Note: SomePath here is the same as above in the code.

**EDIT**
As I mentioned, one can fix the problem of not locating files using:

```
    try {
        m_ssl_context.load_verify_file("SomePath1/server.crt");
        m_ssl_context.use_private_key_file("SomePath2/server.key", asio::ssl::context::pem);
        m_ssl_context.use_tmp_dh_file("SomePath3/dh1024.pem");
        m_ssl_context.use_certificate_chain_file("SomePath1/server.crt");
        m_ssl_context.use_private_key_file("SomePath2/server.key",
            asio::ssl::context::pem);
        m_ssl_context.use_tmp_dh_file("SomePath3/dh1024.pem");
    }
    catch (system::system_error err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

Note that now I'am using dh1024 since 512 was long ago depricated.
Again 'SomePathi' should be the same thing.
Finally, This is only for testing, it's not a good practice to hard code like this.

Comment: You don't seem to take the current working directory into account.

Comment: I tried that as well it didn't work. I put these certificates everywhere. I found the problem for some reason I should do `m_ssl_context.use_certificate_chain_file("SomePath/server.crt")`. there are some odd things about the openssl. when I look for default config path from inside the C++ (using `CONF_get1_default_config_file()`), it gives me the location for the other installed openssl but when I look for the default certificate path, it gives me the vcpkg-installed openssl related location.